# Using BigInt in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I believe I should be able to use BigInt now in TypeScript...but changing some code base to use it and I get "Cannot find name 'BigInt'. (2304)" any thought on why I am getting this error?

```
$ cat test.ts 
let x = BigInt(123)
console.log(x.toString())

$ tsc test.ts 
test.ts:1:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt'.

1 let x = BigInt(123)
          ~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

How do I start using BigInt now within TypeScript?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`BigInt` support has been added on [TypeScript 3.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#bigint); make sure your version is compatible.

But on top of that, you need to decide how `BigInt` will be supported on the context of your script - will you provide polyfills, or will you only run your script on environments that are guaranteed to have `BigInt` support?

This means [you will need `esnext`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#caveats-1) as your build target (likely on `tsconfig.json`'s `target` field), since `BigInt` is not compatible with previous ECMAScript versions.

If you do include a `BigInt` polyfill, you can use `esnext.bigint` as part of the `lib` field during transpilation. This adds the needed definitions to the process.

Comment: I am using 3.7.2 of TS. I dont intend to have a polyfill, as I intend to run within browsers that already have native support. Shouldnt compilation then work out of the box?

Comment: Yes, but you need to set the `target` to `esnext` (the default is `es3`) via the command line or `tsconfig`, so it doesn't attempt to provide any syntax polyfilling of its own. With `exnext`, it basically just trusts you want a modern JavaScript output. This field exists to remove ambiguity. So I'd say, yes, it works out-of-the-box, but you need to be clear on what the intent is.

Comment: @Jonathan  Your comment appears to be unrelated to this answer. Perhaps it would be more suitable as a separate answer? I'd also appreciate some context around it rather than just a code snippet - why does this work, what does it do, and what makes it different to the other answers?

Answer (score 4):

It works for me to add  ***esnext.bigint*** in ***lib*** .

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6","esnext.bigint"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I should be add "node" to types in my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "outDir": "build/module",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": ["node"] // <--- this one
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your answer

Comment: for mem this line worked: "types": ["node"]