# Unable to use BigInt in typescript version 3.1.6. error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt'

Tags: typescript, biginteger, bigint

I want to use BigInt in Typescript

```
    private AND = (left: BitwiseNumber, right: BitwiseNumber) => {
     return BigInt(left) & BigInt(right);
    }
```

But it gave me this error:

> src/dir/file-name.ts(190,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt'.

To solve this checked answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456390/using-bigint-in-typescript) question which cited [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#caveats-1) document and suggested me to add `"target": "esnext"` & `"lib": ["esnext.bigint"]`  in file `tsconfig.json`.

but my `tsconfig.json` file already has these values in `target` and `lib` as shown below:

```
    "target": "es2018",
    "lib": ["es2018"],
```

Now if I change value of `target` from `es-2018` to `esnext`. It start throwing other errors. So, My question can I still use `BigInt` in version `3.1.6`? If Not is there any alternate for `BigInt` in this version?

My Typescript version is `3.1.6`

Comment: 10 seconds of searching suggests that bigint support was added to [Typescript 3.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Is there any alternate to use BigInt in typescript version `3.1.6`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) support was added to TypeScript [with the release of TypeScript 3.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#bigint).

If you are unable to upgrade (which is unfortunate, as TypeScript changes quickly enough for this to be a significant source of technical debt), then you cannot use `BigInt` directly.

One approach here is to use a third-party arbitrary-precision integer library instead.  This cannot be a completely transparent replacement; it's not possible to polyfill syntax.  So you won't be able to use BigInt literals like `123n` or the overloaded numeric operators like `BigInt(3) * BigInt(5)`.  Instead you'll need to use methods or functions which give such behavior.

I don't think this is the place to advocate for a particular library, so I'll just use the one I found first when searching: [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js), published in npm as `big-integer`:

```
import bigInt from "big-integer";
```

Then your above code will need to use the [`and()` method](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/blob/master/BigInteger.d.ts#L109) for bitwise-and instead of the `&` operator:

```
  private AND = (left: BitwiseNumber, right: BitwiseNumber) => {
    return bigInt(left).and(bigInt(right));
  };
```

Okay, hope this helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.1.6#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAI2AcwJIDt4DMoRHAIiWQFphMBTZCqAgbgCgGYBPMCuAIWBgHdgAzhQByAVxAIacALxx04yVEYMAxgBsAhgIFc10MHADeDOHDBRgANw0wOAQWEARGXAAUailhgAuLj35CYhI0ADRwFsgAFj5+fIIiCjQAlDIAfEYmpuEUMKJQ6IgoGDDunjBJAHQa6AAmrsTFrhHRSUmMpgC+jB1M6BS8uvqubUxwQA)

Comment: @jacalz! Thanks for the detailed and well written answer +1 for that. After doing some search I found people recommending to upgrade typescript to solve such problem which is quite fair but for some reasons I am not upgrading it for now. So, method left to me was using 3rd party library & I used big-integer from npm because it has my required bitwise AND OR NOT operations and to my surprise you also recommended the same. BUT error occured with this as well, which says: node_modules/big-integer/BigInteger.d.ts(27,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I fixed that by adding "skipLibCheck": true in tsconfig.json. thanks to this issue https://github.com/dubzzz/fast-check/issues/277#issuecomment-450238756

Comment: another issue I faced was, TypeError: big_integer_1.default is not a function
    at AND (/home/al/htmc/api/build/routes/utils.js:12:55).

which was resolved by replacing `import bigInt from "big-integer;"` to  `import * as bigInt from 'big-integer';`. I am documenting these issue here so that it may help someone if future if he/she faces similar issue.