# Unable to use BigInt in typescript version 3.4.5. Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know that BigInt support was added to TypeScript with the release of TypeScript 3.2.
My TypeScript version is 3.4.5 still i am getting the error as:
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt'.
I am using Angular 8.

Note: I did try setting the target to esnext in tsconfig.json but still getting the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456390/using-bigint-in-typescript What's the target version of your build?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using BigInt in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456390/using-bigint-in-typescript)

Comment: I did try setting target to esnext in tsconfig.json but still getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to resolve the error by adding "esnext.bigint" into the "lib" section of tsconfig.json file in my angular 8 project.

Comment: Same problem here. BigInt problems with TS 4.0.2 in my angular 10 project and types/node 14.14. After adding "esnext.bigint" into _tsconfig.base.json_ "lib" section, all is working

Answer (score 0):

Temporary Solution : Add "types": ["node"] in tsconfig.json

Permanent solution : Upgrade tsc