# How to move back to typescript version 3.1.6?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

Our Angular project has typescript version 3.1.6, I just cloned the project and with npm install, I got typescript version 3.1.8. So is there any way to move back to the same version? with 3.1.8 I'm facing error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'. issue while compiling Angular project

Comment: After running npm install, in which file you checked the typescript version ?

Comment: i ran ng v on cmd

Comment: Can you post the value for typescript in package.json ?

Comment: "typescript": "~3.1.0"

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59456518/10315665

Comment: Also good to know if you're having issues with dependency versions (`npm ci`) https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use BigInt in typescript version 3.4.5. Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64338541/unable-to-use-bigint-in-typescript-version-3-4-5-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name)

Comment: I did read that question, however, the issue is that I was not facing error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'. with 3.1.6. but now with 3.1.8 im facing TS2304 everytime i complie

Comment: @AyubJamal did you add `"esnext.bigint"` into the `"lib"` section inside your tsconfig?

Comment: yeah, but that didn't worked

Comment: is the error occurring if you run `npx tsc --noemit` or only in your editor?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `package.json`
Update the value of typescript to  `"typescript": 3.1.6`.
Run npm install.

Comment: i already did that but still facing
ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/fs.d.ts(2456,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.

Comment: Try running npm install after completely removing the node_modules directory

Comment: If your error is only on the editor and ng serve is running fine, change the typescript version in VSCode to "Use Workspace version"